# pandas KeyError, can't find index when using floats

Tags: python, pandas

I am having the following problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(401), index=np.linspace(0, 1, 401))
print(np.linspace(0, 1, 401))
```

We see that `0.47` is in there:

```
[ 0.      0.0025  0.005   0.0075  0.01    0.0125  0.015   0.0175  0.02
  0.0225  0.025   0.0275  0.03    0.0325  0.035   0.0375  0.04    0.0425
  0.045   0.0475  0.05    0.0525  0.055   0.0575  0.06    0.0625  0.065
  0.0675  0.07    0.0725  0.075   0.0775  0.08    0.0825  0.085   0.0875
  0.09    0.0925  0.095   0.0975  0.1     0.1025  0.105   0.1075  0.11
  0.1125  0.115   0.1175  0.12    0.1225  0.125   0.1275  0.13    0.1325
  0.135   0.1375  0.14    0.1425  0.145   0.1475  0.15    0.1525  0.155
  0.1575  0.16    0.1625  0.165   0.1675  0.17    0.1725  0.175   0.1775
  0.18    0.1825  0.185   0.1875  0.19    0.1925  0.195   0.1975  0.2
  0.2025  0.205   0.2075  0.21    0.2125  0.215   0.2175  0.22    0.2225
  0.225   0.2275  0.23    0.2325  0.235   0.2375  0.24    0.2425  0.245
  0.2475  0.25    0.2525  0.255   0.2575  0.26    0.2625  0.265   0.2675
  0.27    0.2725  0.275   0.2775  0.28    0.2825  0.285   0.2875  0.29
  0.2925  0.295   0.2975  0.3     0.3025  0.305   0.3075  0.31    0.3125
  0.315   0.3175  0.32    0.3225  0.325   0.3275  0.33    0.3325  0.335
  0.3375  0.34    0.3425  0.345   0.3475  0.35    0.3525  0.355   0.3575
  0.36    0.3625  0.365   0.3675  0.37    0.3725  0.375   0.3775  0.38
  0.3825  0.385   0.3875  0.39    0.3925  0.395   0.3975  0.4     0.4025
  0.405   0.4075  0.41    0.4125  0.415   0.4175  0.42    0.4225  0.425
  0.4275  0.43    0.4325  0.435   0.4375  0.44    0.4425  0.445   0.4475
  0.45    0.4525  0.455   0.4575  0.46    0.4625  0.465   0.4675  0.47
  0.4725  0.475   0.4775  0.48    0.4825  0.485   0.4875  0.49    0.4925
  0.495   0.4975  0.5     0.5025  0.505   0.5075  0.51    0.5125  0.515
  0.5175  0.52    0.5225  0.525   0.5275  0.53    0.5325  0.535   0.5375
  0.54    0.5425  0.545   0.5475  0.55    0.5525  0.555   0.5575  0.56
  0.5625  0.565   0.5675  0.57    0.5725  0.575   0.5775  0.58    0.5825
  0.585   0.5875  0.59    0.5925  0.595   0.5975  0.6     0.6025  0.605
  0.6075  0.61    0.6125  0.615   0.6175  0.62    0.6225  0.625   0.6275
  0.63    0.6325  0.635   0.6375  0.64    0.6425  0.645   0.6475  0.65
  0.6525  0.655   0.6575  0.66    0.6625  0.665   0.6675  0.67    0.6725
  0.675   0.6775  0.68    0.6825  0.685   0.6875  0.69    0.6925  0.695
  0.6975  0.7     0.7025  0.705   0.7075  0.71    0.7125  0.715   0.7175
  0.72    0.7225  0.725   0.7275  0.73    0.7325  0.735   0.7375  0.74
  0.7425  0.745   0.7475  0.75    0.7525  0.755   0.7575  0.76    0.7625
  0.765   0.7675  0.77    0.7725  0.775   0.7775  0.78    0.7825  0.785
  0.7875  0.79    0.7925  0.795   0.7975  0.8     0.8025  0.805   0.8075
  0.81    0.8125  0.815   0.8175  0.82    0.8225  0.825   0.8275  0.83
  0.8325  0.835   0.8375  0.84    0.8425  0.845   0.8475  0.85    0.8525
  0.855   0.8575  0.86    0.8625  0.865   0.8675  0.87    0.8725  0.875
  0.8775  0.88    0.8825  0.885   0.8875  0.89    0.8925  0.895   0.8975
  0.9     0.9025  0.905   0.9075  0.91    0.9125  0.915   0.9175  0.92
  0.9225  0.925   0.9275  0.93    0.9325  0.935   0.9375  0.94    0.9425
  0.945   0.9475  0.95    0.9525  0.955   0.9575  0.96    0.9625  0.965
  0.9675  0.97    0.9725  0.975   0.9775  0.98    0.9825  0.985   0.9875
  0.99    0.9925  0.995   0.9975  1.    ]
```

Now for example I try `df[0.47]` and get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2133             try:
-> 2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4238)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.Int64Engine._check_type (pandas/index.c:8209)()

KeyError: 0.47

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-76c97f917184> in <module>()
----> 1 df[0.47]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2057             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2058         else:
-> 2059             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2060 
   2061     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2064         # get column
   2065         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2066             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2067 
   2068         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1384         res = cache.get(item)
   1385         if res is None:
-> 1386             values = self._data.get(item)
   1387             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1388             cache[item] = res

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3541 
   3542             if not isnull(item):
-> 3543                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3544             else:
   3545                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:
-> 2136                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2137 
   2138         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4238)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.Int64Engine._check_type (pandas/index.c:8209)()

KeyError: 0.47
```

I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Why use floats as indices?

Comment: Mostly convenience. I would like to be able to select an entry based on a float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is due to float imprecision, you can use the method `get_slice_bound` to return you the ordinal position for that row:

```
In [237]:
df.iloc[df.index.get_slice_bound(0.47, side='left', kind='loc')]

Out[237]:
0    0.854001
Name: 0.47, dtype: float64
```

We can see the real value of that index label:

```
In [238]:
df.index[df.index.get_slice_bound(0.47, side='left', kind='loc')]
Out[238]:
0.47000000000000003
```

Whilst pandas does support `float64Index` it's going to be problematic for exact label lookup by doing this, you'd be better off sticking with the default `Int64Index`

`get_slice_bound` is an undocumented method but the docstring gives you enough info:

```
Signature: df.index.get_slice_bound(label, side, kind) Docstring: Calculate slice bound that corresponds to given label.

Returns leftmost (one-past-the-rightmost if ``side=='right'``) position of given label.

Parameters
---------- label : object side : {'left', 'right'} kind : {'ix', 'loc', 'getitem'}
```

You can also use [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) and pass `method='nearest'` to achieve the same:

```
In [240]:
df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(0.47, method='nearest')]

Out[240]:
0    0.854001
Name: 0.47, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, `get_loc` is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

The representation may be the same but the value may be slightly different and the `hash` is then different.

The values may be different and the display is still `0.47` for both, which is misleading.

=> You cannot index your elements by a float key reliably.

Instead, maybe use *decimals* as keys, or rounded values.