# Most elegant way to simulate float columns and index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, which, let's say is meant to represent a 'confusion matrix' (i.e. the index and columns are the same). Each index / column is represented by a float, as this corresponds to explicit, predetermined questionnaire values.

However, this presents a problem, since using float representations in pandas is known to be a dangerous thing to do. Example:

Say I have this code:

```
>>> import numpy, pandas
>>> Labels = numpy.arange(1, 3.5, 0.2)
>>> Data = numpy.random.randint( low = 0, high = 100, size = (13,13) )
>>> DF = pandas.DataFrame( index = Labels, columns = Labels, data = Data )
```

Resulting in this lovely-looking dataframe:

```
>>> DF
     1.0  1.2  1.4  1.6  1.8  2.0  2.2  2.4  2.6  2.8  3.0  3.2  3.4
1.0   77   35    5   40    9   45   14   85   16   63   43   72   92
1.2   96   93   12   87   14    3   79   53   19   53    4   41   47
1.4    1   79    9   94   95   52   64   71   97    2   57   12   75
1.6   55   48   55   14   90   57   75   39   16   86   42   41   50
1.8   31   60   10   89   70   66   31   74   87   26   83   17   77
2.0   95   27   77   59   54   31   73   22   64   49   84   38   47
2.2   66   49   66   28   91   74   54   85   62   56   36   18   39
2.4   38   59   89   90   44   22   66   92   29   22   71   22   89
2.6   58   42   46   88   86   29    1   34   38   76   27   73    6
2.8   14    5   80   61    5   18   44   76   84   21   42   87   82
3.0   41   67   37   64   92   50   61   48   49   43   47   37   81
3.2   29   99   47   10   61   17   28   35    7   30   37   70   33
3.4   56   95   21   12   48   31   61   71   41   19   13   14   52
```

If I try to get a value at the index / column reported visually:

```
>>> DF.get_value(2.0, 2.0)
[...]
KeyError: 2.0
```

The reason of course being that, Labels internally has a different representation to what is displayed when merely 'pretty' printing. E.g.:

```
>>> Labels
array([1. , 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2. , 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 2.8, 3. , 3.2, 3.4])

>>> [str(i) for i in Labels]
['1.0', '1.2', '1.4', '1.5999999999999999', '1.7999999999999998', '1.9999999999999998', '2.1999999999999997', '2.3999999999999995', '2.5999999999999996', '2.8', '2.9999999999999996', '3.1999999999999993', '3.3999999999999995']
```

I'm happy to use a string rather than a float as an index (i.e. something like `DF.get_value('2.0', '2.0')` instead), however, I do not want to resort to writing something like `['1.0', '1.2', '1.4', ...]` etc by hand. I cannot imagine there isn't a better way to get this kind of thing to work.

Am I missing something obvious?

**EDIT**. I'm realising as I type, as is often the case when asking a question on SO, that I could simply create the index array using string formatting. But I'm open to other suggestions in case someone has something even more obvious to recommend (particularly if it involves *not* using strings in the first place).

Comment: Ummm, better using np.isclose

Comment: that's because your dataframe may not be what you expect it to be. Why I run your code, I do not get the same dataframe. Run `DF.columns` and let me know what you get. I get `Float64Index([               1.0,                1.2,                1.4,
              1.5999999999999999, 1.7999999999999998, 1.9999999999999998,
              2.1999999999999997, 2.3999999999999995, 2.5999999999999996,
                             2.8, 2.9999999999999996, 3.1999999999999993,
              3.3999999999999995],
             dtype='float64')`

Comment: @MattR yes exactly, sorry if I didn't make it clear. So we know this is what the problem is and why something like `DF.get_value(2.0, 2.0)` is not guaranteed to work, and that using floats as indices for dataframes is [generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42696801/4183191). But I'm wondering if there's an elegant way to get around this problem (the `iloc` solution in that link doesn't seem much better than string formatting in my mind ... but maybe that's as best as it gets)

Comment: @W-B `np.isclose` is interesting ... how would you use that with the indices though? Are you effectively suggesting 'boolean' indexing? (e.g. something like this? `DF.loc[numpy.isclose( Labels, 2.0 ), numpy.isclose( Labels, 2.0 )]` )